# Disabling JButton outside initialize

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am at the end of creating my `Tic tac toe` game but I encountered a problem with disabling `JButton`.

After *isThisTheEnd* method recognize that the game should end, I was planing to disable all buttons, but it is impossible to do outside *initialize*.
Is there a way to do this, also why it is possible to setText for a textField but setEnabled not?

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/7isvtQ31)

```
public void isThisTheEnd()
{
    //vertical
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      if(board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[1][i]==board[2][i])
            textEnd.setText((turn==1?"X":"O") + " wins!");

    //horizontal
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       if(board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][1]==board[i][2])
            textEnd.setText((turn==1?"X":"O") + " wins!");

    //diagonal
    if((board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2]) || (board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[0][2]))
        textEnd.setText((turn==1?"X":"O") + " wins!");
    else 
        nextTurn();
}


 private void initialize() {

    btn1.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.disabledForeground"));
    btn1.setBounds(36, 86, 120, 120);
    window.getContentPane().add(btn1);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    btn1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn1.setText((turn==1?"X":"O"));
            board[0][0]=turn;
            isThisTheEnd();
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Please post a [mre] so we can see how the code is set up and why you're stating "this is impossible to do...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// EDIT:
Problem was, that the variable was defined inside a function and could not be used in another function, see comments below this answer.

This was the old solution, not related to the problem in this case:

Try this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
  // Disable buttons here
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt work.
I tried :
  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
  btn1.setEnabled(false);
  }
 });`
But error mesage stays the same - _btn1 cannot be resolved_

Comment: Okay, there we get closer to the problem.
The problem is not that you cannot disable the button itself. The problem is, that your variable btn1 is not defined outside of initialize.
As i don't see your whole code i'm not sure how it works exactly but probably at the start of initialize() you definde your button like `JButton btn1 = new JButton();` and then use it. As btn1 is only defined in this methode initialize() has access to it but your other method does not.
To resolve this try to define your button as a class variable `JButton btn1;` in your class outside of any method

Comment: And then initialize it in your initialize() method using `btn1 = new JButton():`. You probably don't need the invokeLater method then.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had my `btn1` defined in `initialize`.I followed your instruction and now it works. Thank you very much :)
P.S.Earlier I added a link to the full code.